# How to output strings from a list of Objects using Repeater

Tags: c#, .net, list, data-binding, repeater

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about this but I'm trying to show some search results using a repeater control. The query is written in the code behind page and i cant figure out how to bind the results to the control. So far I've created a list of saleItem objects, the saleItem object contains the string i want to show in the repeater.

**Search.aspx.cs**

```
List<SaleItem> resultsList = new List<SaleItem>();

  SqlDataReader reader = doMainQuery.ExecuteReader();

  while (reader.Read())
  {
    SaleItem newItem = new SaleItem((string)reader["saleTitle"]);
    resultsList.Add(newItem);
  }
  showResults.DataSource = resultsList;
  showResults.DataBind();
```

**SaleItem.cs**

```
public class SaleItem
{
    private String connectionString;
    public string saleTitle;

    public SaleItem(string s)
    {
        saleTitle = s;
    }

    public string  getTitle()
    {
        return saleTitle;
    }
}
```

**Search.aspx**

id like to be able to show the title in a similar way to this, any ideas?

```
<asp:repeater
        id="showResults"  

        Runat="server"   >

        <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("saleTitle")%></ItemTemplate> // resultsList.SaleItem.getTitle()?
        </asp:repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your code as follow

```
public class SaleItem
{    
    public string saleTitle {get;set;}   
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, Func<SqlDataReader, T> projection)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return projection(reader);
        }
    }
}

List<SaleItem> resultsList = new List<SaleItem>();

SqlDataReader reader = doMainQuery.ExecuteReader();
var resultsList = reader.Select(x => new SaleItem { saleTitle = x["saleTitle"].ToString() }).Distinct().ToList();

showResults.DataSource = resultsList;
showResults.DataBind();


<asp:repeater id="showResults" Runat="server"   >
    <ItemTemplate>
      <%# Eval("saleTitle")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Comment: thanks @Peyman although i forgot to mention that i was going to use the while loop to remove any duplicate rows returned, caused by the joins in the SQLstatement, by only creating the saleItem object and addding it to the list if the saleId was different to the previous row. is there a way to deal with that issue?

Comment: @Slartybartfast, you can use distinct to remove any duplicated data

Comment: hi @Peyman i tried renaming  var resultsList to  var resultsList2 and when run i get a source is not IEnumerable<> exception? im quite confused by your code could you please explain whats going on on the var resultList line... thanks

Comment: Hi @Slartybartfast, I changed the code, and I've tested. It's working.